# Sync calendar events/appointments in a java application to other mail accounts on mobile device using CalDAV

Tags: java, calendar, icalendar, caldav

I have a calendar feature in my software application in which I can create events, tasks, appointments and other normal calendar features.

I want to have a feature where I can synchronize my calendar events to my iPhone or Android phone calendar apps.  I found that I could use CalDAV protocol (RFC 4791) to implement this, but I am not sure how to go about it.

Do I have to create both a CalDAV server and client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an excellent guide on how to write a CalDAV client: [Building a CalDAV client](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/).

Unless you have very special needs, you probably don't need to write a CalDAV server, there are [plenty of them](http://caldav.calconnect.org/implementations/servers.html) already.

Another useful resources is the [CalDAV Home](http://caldav.calconnect.org/index.html) website of CalConnect (the standards organisation working on CalDAV).